# Spring Cloud DataFlow shell command "not currently available"

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-shell

I **sometimes** get this error:

`2016-10-20T15:38:24+0200 WARN main o.s.s.c.SimpleParser:131 - Command 'app register --name email --type source --uri <uriToMyDockerImage>' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)`

At other times it works as expected.

Note that I start the shell with `--dataflow.uri=<url> --spring.shell.commandFile=<path>`.

Why would the `app register` command not be available? What can I do to make it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would happen if the last time the server tried to connect to the REST API of the dataflow server, the server was down.
This happens at

1. shell start
2. everytime you do `dataflow config server <url>`

Comment: @eric: perhaps you meant to add: `dataflow config server <url>` :)

Comment: I start the shell with `--dataflow.uri=<url> --spring.shell.commandFile=<path>`.

Comment: @eric: I guess the first "server" should be "shell"?

Comment: no, it's really "shell": at shell start, the shell tries to connect to the default server URL (http://localhost:9393). I hope this makes sense

Comment: Sometimes it takes the SCDF server a while (e.g. over 30 seconds) to become responsive. This is _after_ Kubernetes reports it as `Ready`. Waiting until the SCDF server responds before starting the shell fixes the issue.